# @Output changing boolean state

Tags: angular

I am trying to change the state of a boolean from child to parent. This is what I have so far.

**child Component**

```
@Input() state: boolean;
  @Output() show = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() hide = new EventEmitter();


   onHover() {
    this.state = true;
    this.show.emit(this.state);
    console.log("state is " + this.state);


  }
  onHoverOut() {
    this.state = false;
    this.hide.emit(this.state);
    console.log("state is " + this.state);

}
```

**child.html**

```
<a (mouseover)="onHover(show.state)" (mouseleave)="onHoverOut(hide.state)">random Link</a>
```

**parent Component**

```
@Component({
   selector: 'my-app',
   template: '<h3 (show)="toggleState" (hide)="toggleState">toggle state: {{boolshow}}</h3>',
})
export class AppComponent {
     toggleState: boolean;
     boolshow = this.toggleState;
}
```

I am not seeing {{boolshow}} changing when I am hovering over the link. any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: There is no relation bet parent and child. You don't even pass `state` variable from parent to child.

Comment: I really want to understand, and I am not. I thought that the `(mouseover)="onHover(show.state)` does that.... and then  picks it up in the parent component in the h3 tag logic `(show)="toggleState"`

Comment: What is your child selector?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1) **@Input** and **@Output** will work when you have ***Parent & Child*** scenario. I don't think you have it !
2) You are dealing with so many things, when things can be so simple as shown here.

---

**Working Demo :  https://plnkr.co/edit/AsmA5DGYTNZNLEAd2O7s?p=preview**

**NOTE:** here, I have optimized it to certain level. I still can go beyond this, but for understanding purpose I think this is it.

---

**Parent**

```
import { Component, ElementRef,Renderer  } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h3>toggle state: {{boolshow}}</h3>
  <child [state]="boolshow"  (toggle)="boolshow=$event" ></child>  //<<<=== here we have set parent relation with child component
  `,

})
export class AppComponent {
  boolshow = true;
}
```

**Child**

```
import { Component, ElementRef,Renderer,Input,Output,EventEmitter  } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `
  <a (mouseover)="onHover()" (mouseleave)="onHoverOut()">random Link</a>
  `
})
export class Child {

  @Input() state: boolean;
  @Output() toggle = new EventEmitter();
  onHover() {
    this.state = true;
    this.toggle.emit(this.state);
    console.log("state is " + this.state);
  }
  onHoverOut() {
    this.state = false;
    this.toggle.emit(this.state);
    console.log("state is " + this.state);
 }
}
```

Comment: I have another quick question, what do you do If your child has no selector? i.e its in the `<router-outlet>` tag or something, I guess this would apply the opposite way, like parent to child @micronyks

Comment: Then it becomes sibling components having no relationship. So in that case you can use `service with Rxjs library (BehaviourSubject)` and make it work for your as you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can also simplify the code with

```
[(state)]="boolshow"
```

Parent

```
import { Component, ElementRef,Renderer  } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h3>toggle state: {{boolshow}}</h3>
  <child [(state)]="boolshow" ></child>
  `,

})
export class AppComponent {
  boolshow = true;
}
```

Child

```
import { Component, ElementRef,Renderer,Input,Output,EventEmitter  } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `
  <a (mouseover)="onHover()" (mouseleave)="onHoverOut()">random Link</a>
  `
})
export class Child {

  @Input() state: boolean;
  @Output() changeState: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();

  onHover() {
    this.state = true;
    this.changeState.emit(this.state);
    console.log("state is " + this.state);
  }
  onHoverOut() {
    this.state = false;
    this.changeState.emit(this.state);
    console.log("state is " + this.state);
  }

}
```

Comment: `changeState` needs to become `stateChange` according to the documentation here: https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding#how-two-way-binding-works